# Web2py app versioning

Tags: web2py

I'm wondering about how can I setup a Windows environment to versioning a Web2py app

I have more than one developer working in only one web2py app, but the great problem is the
changes control over the code.

Actually we have every PC running its own Web2py server...

Somebody are working with the same setup?

There are a good way to brings all changes to one consolidated version?

Thanks in Advance.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a revision control system? That's exactly what you need. I'm not much for developing on windows, but I think TortiseSVN is a popular GUI interface to SVN (subversion), one of the more popular Revision Control Systems.

Basically you will have a central repository that holds all of the code and all of the changes you've ever made. You can roll back to any version and can combine different edits from different developers into one master codebase. Then you can have different web2py servers check out different versions if desired.

You'll have to figure out how to install and set up the repository on your own, but this should get yo started:

TortiseSVN (the CLIENT): http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/   <- this lets you check in and check out code
VisualSVN (the SERVER): http://www.visualsvn.com/server/  <- this holds all the code

Comment: I'm moving my Web2py App to a Mercurial repo on a linux server to try, Thanks

Comment: good -- mercurial is the best RCS in my opinion. I'm not sure of your experience with repos, but just wanted to point out mercurial is decentralized vs centralized, but I think that adds more flexibility and is more sane than CVS/SVN. Hope this solves your issue (... and becomes accepted at some point :)